# Get our stacktravel account to use #travel in the tweets

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Our [Travel Stackexchange twitter account - @stacktravel](https://twitter.com/StackTravel) tweets out questions with the used tags on the questions.

Some of the tags we use are not very common on twitter, especially among the travel writers / tweeters.

It makes so much sense to add #travel onto each tweet, if there's space, that it'd get seen a lot more. (I'd almost suggest other event ones like #ttot and #tni but that's sort of hijacking their convos ;))

However, #travel would get a lot more of these travel questions seen.

Also: note that you can see the historical stats of this account by [checking twittercounter.com](http://twittercounter.com/StackTravel?manual_update=1).

Comment: I think this might be useful for other sites in the network too. (i.e. bicycles, the great outdoors, seasoned advice, etc). Worth bringing it to the mother meta if note discussed before?

Comment: @Bernhard Good idea, [it's been suggested on meta meta for everyone but the suggestion's not been followed up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225175/add-site-specific-hashtag-to-twitter-feeds). Looks like the deal is "sites can do it if they want".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way our system is designed, the only easy way for us to do this is to *replace* the question tags with #travel. However, looking at the current status of the current top @stacktravel hashtags (#customsandimmigration, #insurance, #visas) it doesn't seem like they're really very valuable. So, okay! I'll get this enabled for you soon.